# Group isomorphism between $(\mathbb{Z}[x], +)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}^+, \cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I'm looking for a group isomorphism between the group of integer polynomials (with addition) and the group of positive rationals (with multiplication).

I was thinking a map between generators of $\mathbb{Q}^*$, $1/p$, where $p$ is prime to irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but I am not exactly sure how it works. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Define $$f:\Bbb{Z}[x]\to \Bbb Q^*:x^n\mapsto p_n$$ extended by linearity, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number. Show that $f$ is injective and surjective using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Missed the bit about *positive* rationals. :) Nice answer, +1.